# What means T.alloc

Tags: keras, theano

I'm learning keras and I'm using a code about music generation to learn. I have checked the code and I have showed this, I think this is theano:

```
start_note_values = T.alloc(np.array(0, dtype=np.int8), 5 * 128, 1, 2)
```

The function is:

```
def y_labels(y): 
    start_note_values = T.alloc(np.array(0, dtype=np.int8), BATCH_SIZE * NUM_TIMESTEPS, 1, OUTPUT_LAYER)
    correct_choices = y[:, :, :-1, :].reshape((BATCH_SIZE * NUM_TIMESTEPS, NUM_NOTES - 1, OUTPUT_LAYER))        
    features = T.concatenate([start_note_values, correct_choices], axis=1)
    return features.reshape((BATCH_SIZE, NUM_TIMESTEPS, NUM_NOTES, OUTPUT_LAYER)).transpose((0, 2, 1, 3)).reshape((BATCH_SIZE * NUM_NOTES, NUM_TIMESTEPS, OUTPUT_LAYER))

get_labels_shape = lambda shape: [BATCH_SIZE * NUM_NOTES, NUM_TIMESTEPS, OUTPUT_LAYER]

previous_notes = Sequential([
    Lambda(y_labels, output_shape=get_labels_shape, batch_input_shape=(BATCH_SIZE, NUM_TIMESTEPS, NUM_NOTES, OUTPUT_LAYER), name='y_labels')
])
```

I don't understand what it means, can someone explain me? The input has this format:

```
X = (440, 128, 300)
```

There is a way to right this in keras?
Thank you guys!

Comment: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.alloc

Comment: Thank you @Matias, do you know how to implement this in Keras?